# How to develop the single application for iphone, but load different contains

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How we can develop the single application for iphone, but load different contains.

Comment: Please make your question clear. What do u mean by contains???

Comment: contains means i want to load different background ,different data  etc.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify more than that, I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load a different user interface? You can call loadNibNamed:owner:options.

Usually your app's first nib is specified in your Info.plist and is loaded automatically.  But I don't think that is a requirement.  You should be able to start up you program with no nib at all, then load it programmatically with the above method.